# Unable print the name and price

Tags: python, json, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Here is the link https://www.adidas.com/us/continental-80-shoes/G27707.html when i hit request to fetch the data from this website it not print any data

```
import requests
import time

url = "https://www.adidas.com/api/metadata/pdp?"


#url=/continental-80-shoes/G27707.html&sitePath=us
params = {
    'sitePath': 'us',
    'productName': 'continental-80-shoes'
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36'
}

res = requests.get(url,params=params,headers=headers)
data=res.json()
time.sleep(4)
print(data)
for item in res.json()['itemList']['items']:
    print(item)
    itemRes = requests.get('https://www.adidas.com/api/search/product/'+item['productId'],headers=headers)  
    print(item['displayName'],itemRes.json()['price'])
```

Comment: What data do you want to get?

Comment: please check your URL, as I try to open the URL with params it does not return any data

Comment: i want to get the name and price from adidas

Comment: maziyank same thing happen with me it not open any data

Comment: How did you get from the link you give at the top of the question (which does return HTML) to the `url` and `params` you have in your script (which returns `{"message":"metadata not found"}`)

Comment: I get the link from Dev tool in Networks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url is not correct. There were a few other errors I fixed in the code as well. Try:

```
import requests
import time

url = "https://www.adidas.com/api/plp/content-engine/search"

params = {
    'sitePath': 'us',
    'query': 'continental 80 shoes'
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36'
}


res = requests.get(url,params=params,headers=headers)
data=res.json()
time.sleep(4)
#print(data)
for item in data['raw']['itemList']['items']:
    #print(item)
    itemRes = requests.get('https://www.adidas.com/api/search/product/' + item['productId']  + '?sitePath=us',headers=headers).json()
    print(item['displayName'],itemRes['price'])
```

**Output:**

```
Continental 80 Shoes 100
Terrex Free Hiker Parley Hiking Shoes 200
Terrex Swift R2 GORE-TEX Hiking Shoes 140
Terrex AX3 GORE-TEX Hiking Shoes 120
Terrex Free Hiker Parley Hiking Shoes 200
Terrex Swift R2 GORE-TEX Hiking Shoes 140
Continental 80 Shoes 100
Terrex AX3 Hiking Shoes 80
Terrex Free Hiker Hiking Shoes 200
Terrex Agravic GORE-TEX Trail Running Shoes 140
Terrex AX3 Hiking Shoes 80
Terrex Two Ultra Parley Trail Running Shoes 180
Terrex Two Ultra Parley Trail Running Shoes 180
Terrex Two Ultra Parley Trail Running Shoes 180
Terrex Free Hiker Parley Hiking Shoes 200
Terrex Two Ultra Parley Trail Running Shoes 180
Terrex Folgian Hiker Hiking Shoes 120
Continental 80 Shoes 100
Continental 80 Shoes 110
Continental 80 Shoes 100
Continental 80 Shoes 85
Terrex AX3 Hiking Shoes 80
Terrex Free Hiker Parley Hiking Shoes 200
Continental 80 Shoes 80
Terrex Two Ultra Parley Trail Running Shoes 180
Continental 80 Shoes 80
Continental 80 Shoes 55
Terrex Free Hiker Blue Hiking Shoes 200
Terrex Free Hiker Blue Hiking Shoes 200
Continental 80 Shoes 80
```

To get other info, a few ways to go. 1: some of the data is in the `<script>` tags, including the reviews, but only the first 5. There are various api endpoints to get what you need. Check the example below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import math

    
url = 'https://www.adidas.com/us/continental-80-shoes/G27707.html'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
script = soup.find('script').text
jsonData = json.loads(script)

name = jsonData['name']
images = jsonData['image']


reviews_url = 'https://www.adidas.com/api/models/AQU30/reviews'
payload = {
'includeLocales': 'en%2A',
'limit': '100',
'offset': '0',
'sort': 'newest'}

jsonData = requests.get(reviews_url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
total_reviews = jsonData['totalResults']
total_pages = math.ceil(total_reviews/100)

reviews = []
for page in range(0,total_pages+1):
    payload.update({'offset':'%s' %(page*100)})
    jsonData = requests.get(reviews_url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
    reviews += jsonData['reviews']
    print('Page %s of %s' %(page,total_pages))
```

**Output:**

```
print(name)
Continental 80 Shoes
```

Images:

```
print(images)
['https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/c6f0aede76f849a18a27a91500a0c8c9_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_01_standard.jpg', 'https://assets.adidas.com/videos/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/dd37d9bb5cd54406b36faa8d00fb8c22_d98c/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_video.jpg', 'https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/690c7ca0531a450187cda91500a0dffa_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_02_standard.jpg', 'https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/fde9d7c8cde6427aae8ca91500a0ec61_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_03_standard.jpg', 'https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/01d85160ccd442a59954a91500a120cf_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_04_standard.jpg', 'https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/73c3160607ab42a3816ca91500a12de3_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_05_standard.jpg', 'https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/46bcee5e26084cffb1aba91500a0d487_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_06_standard.jpg', 'https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/5ecde2b36fb4425ca67aa97b012ee1e4_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_07_standard.jpg', 'https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/50f65fa2a60946a8990ba91500a13a53_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_41_detail.jpg', 'https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/3c7047a003154900905fa91500a1449f_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_42_detail.jpg', 'https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/fec75a9048404de0b32ca91500a14f19_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_43_detail.jpg']
```

I only printed first 10 reviews here (there are 1759 reviews):

```
print(reviews[:10])
[{'id': '131062281', 'userNickname': 'Riley67', 'title': "Best Shoes I've Owned", 'formattedDate': 'February 23, 2021', 'submissionTime': '2021-02-23T23:01:17.000+00:00', 'text': "These shoes are the best shoes I've ever bought. They've lasted me 6 months with daily use and have lots more life in them. They look good new and look good with the beat up shoe look as well. Amazing, lasting quality that I haven't found with any other shoes before.", 'isRecommended': True, 'rating': 5, 'ratingRange': 5, 'positiveFeedbackCount': 0, 'negativeFeedbackCount': 0, 'photos': [], 'badges': [], 'responses': [], 'locale': 'en_US'}, {'id': '131051782', 'userNickname': 'skysound', 'title': 'Best purchase', 'formattedDate': 'February 23, 2021', 'submissionTime': '2021-02-23T17:37:48.000+00:00', 'text': 'I love the style, but a bit too small, so I will buy other size', 'isRecommended': True, 'rating': 4, 'ratingRange': 5, 'positiveFeedbackCount': 0, 'negativeFeedbackCount': 0, 'photos': [], 'badges': [], 'responses': [], 'locale': 'en_US'}, {'id': '130996430', 'userNickname': 'WillyDaMn', 'title': 'I’ll buy here again.', 'formattedDate': 'February 22, 2021', 'submissionTime': '2021-02-22T16:10:23.000+00:00', 'text': 'I live on snow area and still confortable and clean.', 'isRecommended': True, 'rating': 5, 'ratingRange': 5, 'positiveFeedbackCount': 0, 'negativeFeedbackCount': 0, 'photos': [{'thumbnailUrl': 'https://photos-us.bazaarvoice.com/photo/2/cGhvdG86YWRpZGFzZ2xvYmFs/fede8014-a033-5e22-97e0-2be9d9890379', 'normalUrl': 'https://photos-us.bazaarvoice.com/photo/2/cGhvdG86YWRpZGFzZ2xvYmFs/5fa3d0af-7867-5691-9be0-04faa6fe43f1'}], 'badges': ['VerifiedPurchaser'], 'responses': [], 'locale': 'en_US'}, {'id': '130976697', 'userNickname': 'Nickgirl', 'title': 'Love the old styles.', 'formattedDate': 'February 22, 2021', 'submissionTime': '2021-02-22T08:02:53.000+00:00', 'text': 'Love this old style look the color is bright just like online i see myself buying more.sneaker is very comfortable.', 'isRecommended': True, 'rating': 4, 'ratingRange': 5, 'positiveFeedbackCount': 0, 'negativeFeedbackCount': 0, 'photos': [], 'badges': ['VerifiedPurchaser'], 'responses': [], 'locale': 'en_US'}, {'id': '130943890', 'userNickname': 'AlexR09', 'title': 'Classic. Totally worth it.', 'formattedDate': 'February 21, 2021', 'submissionTime': '2021-02-21T03:08:01.000+00:00', 'text': 'Looks great and fits perfectly as well. You can’t get wrong with it.', 'isRecommended': True, 'rating': 5, 'ratingRange': 5, 'positiveFeedbackCount': 0, 'negativeFeedbackCount': 0, 'photos': [], 'badges': ['VerifiedPurchaser'], 'responses': [], 'locale': 'en_US'}, {'id': '130926424', 'userNickname': 'NateH44', 'title': 'A very good product', 'formattedDate': 'February 20, 2021', 'submissionTime': '2021-02-20T12:52:06.000+00:00', 'text': 'A very good product, but improvements can be made. A little more memory cushion for the soul of your foot. In the toe area where the shoe laces is Assemble area it cramps up in the toes of the foot.', 'isRecommended': True, 'rating': 4, 'ratingRange': 5, 'positiveFeedbackCount': 0, 'negativeFeedbackCount': 0, 'photos': [{'thumbnailUrl': 'https://photos-us.bazaarvoice.com/photo/2/cGhvdG86YWRpZGFzZ2xvYmFs/00e5bd10-ee7d-54dd-99db-ec22cce270ff', 'normalUrl': 'https://photos-us.bazaarvoice.com/photo/2/cGhvdG86YWRpZGFzZ2xvYmFs/d32630e2-d54b-5e57-9821-d32cb264952a'}], 'badges': ['VerifiedPurchaser'], 'responses': [], 'locale': 'en_US'}, {'id': '130848443', 'userNickname': 'MrsBeav', 'title': 'Very comfortable!', 'formattedDate': 'February 18, 2021', 'submissionTime': '2021-02-18T10:27:33.000+00:00', 'text': 'Comfortable good looking casual shoe.  Great for being on your feet all day.', 'isRecommended': True, 'rating': 5, 'ratingRange': 5, 'positiveFeedbackCount': 0, 'negativeFeedbackCount': 0, 'photos': [], 'badges': ['VerifiedPurchaser'], 'responses': [], 'locale': 'en_US'}, {'id': '130830499', 'userNickname': 'Jdogg3435', 'title': 'I got them on sale', 'formattedDate': 'February 17, 2021', 'submissionTime': '2021-02-17T19:41:10.000+00:00', 'text': 'I got them on sale because they didnt have the ones I wanted. I ended up really liking these shoes and now they are my favorite everyday wear.', 'isRecommended': False, 'rating': 5, 'ratingRange': 5, 'positiveFeedbackCount': 0, 'negativeFeedbackCount': 0, 'photos': [], 'badges': ['VerifiedPurchaser'], 'responses': [], 'locale': 'en_US'}, {'id': '130785106', 'userNickname': 'Beejis', 'title': 'Good stuff! Comfortable and stylish - now I just need some pants to match.', 'formattedDate': 'February 16, 2021', 'submissionTime': '2021-02-16T21:13:57.000+00:00', 'text': 'I would recommend to anyone. Great shoes that are stylish and built of the highest quality.', 'isRecommended': True, 'rating': 5, 'ratingRange': 5, 'positiveFeedbackCount': 0, 'negativeFeedbackCount': 0, 'photos': [], 'badges': ['VerifiedPurchaser'], 'responses': [], 'locale': 'en_US'}, {'id': '130697684', 'userNickname': 'BossLadyLLC', 'title': 'Dope shoes', 'formattedDate': 'February 15, 2021', 'submissionTime': '2021-02-15T10:40:03.000+00:00', 'text': 'Durable\nComfortable shoes\nStylish and affordable price', 'isRecommended': True, 'rating': 5, 'ratingRange': 5, 'positiveFeedbackCount': 0, 'negativeFeedbackCount': 0, 'photos': [], 'badges': ['VerifiedPurchaser'], 'responses': [], 'locale': 'en_US'}]
```

Comment: This is right but i want to get continental 80 shoes product detail

Comment: like what? in your post all you said is you want name and price.

Comment: I want to get this link  https://www.adidas.com/us/continental-80-shoes/G27707.html product detail

Comment: Right but what from that? The reviews? Availability/sizes? The api isn’t the best/straightforward it appears. Takes a little work.

Comment: i want to extract name image and rating from this https://www.adidas.com/us/continental-80-shoes/G27707.html