# Extract these url in separate line with the help of Regex

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, webdriver

Want to remove `""` , and `[]` also

```
"image":["https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/c6f0aede76f849a18a27a91500a0c8c9_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_01_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/videos/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/dd37d9bb5cd54406b36faa8d00fb8c22_d98c/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_video.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/690c7ca0531a450187cda91500a0dffa_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_02_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/fde9d7c8cde6427aae8ca91500a0ec61_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_03_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/01d85160ccd442a59954a91500a120cf_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_04_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/73c3160607ab42a3816ca91500a12de3_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_05_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/46bcee5e26084cffb1aba91500a0d487_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_06_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/5ecde2b36fb4425ca67aa97b012ee1e4_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_07_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/50f65fa2a60946a8990ba91500a13a53_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_41_detail.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/3c7047a003154900905fa91500a1449f_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_42_detail.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/fec75a9048404de0b32ca91500a14f19_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_43_detail.jpg"]
```

Comment: any reason you need to use regex? 
This looks like a json, and they work like dicts in Python so shuld be quite straight forward if you dont have to use regex

Comment: so what method to use

Comment: why are you asking under a different name today?

Comment: @BendikKnapstad How can you tell?

Comment: hes using my answer from yesterday in this question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66365160/unable-to-capture-records-name-price-and-rating-and-image-in-requests-python/66369500#66369500

Comment: @BendikKnapstad I believe it's just shear coincidence that this user found your answer and used it :)

Comment: @AnnZen that may be :)

Comment: wonder if this is some type of assignment. I answered a similar question as well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66352130/unable-print-the-name-and-price/66356013#66356013)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure how you are getting your data but some thing like this:

```
data = {"image":["https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/c6f0aede76f849a18a27a91500a0c8c9_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_01_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/videos/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/dd37d9bb5cd54406b36faa8d00fb8c22_d98c/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_video.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/690c7ca0531a450187cda91500a0dffa_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_02_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/fde9d7c8cde6427aae8ca91500a0ec61_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_03_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/01d85160ccd442a59954a91500a120cf_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_04_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/73c3160607ab42a3816ca91500a12de3_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_05_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/46bcee5e26084cffb1aba91500a0d487_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_06_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/5ecde2b36fb4425ca67aa97b012ee1e4_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_07_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/50f65fa2a60946a8990ba91500a13a53_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_41_detail.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/3c7047a003154900905fa91500a1449f_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_42_detail.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/fec75a9048404de0b32ca91500a14f19_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_43_detail.jpg"]}
```

data is now a dict with a single key image, witch again contains a list of urls.

Simply access the items like this: `data["image"][0]` for the first item.

or you can loop through them all:

```
for image in data["image"]:
   #do stuff with image
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regular expression:

```
import re

s = """
"image":["https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/c6f0aede76f849a18a27a91500a0c8c9_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_01_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/videos/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/dd37d9bb5cd54406b36faa8d00fb8c22_d98c/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_video.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/690c7ca0531a450187cda91500a0dffa_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_02_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/fde9d7c8cde6427aae8ca91500a0ec61_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_03_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/01d85160ccd442a59954a91500a120cf_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_04_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/73c3160607ab42a3816ca91500a12de3_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_05_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/46bcee5e26084cffb1aba91500a0d487_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_06_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/5ecde2b36fb4425ca67aa97b012ee1e4_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_07_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/50f65fa2a60946a8990ba91500a13a53_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_41_detail.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/3c7047a003154900905fa91500a1449f_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_42_detail.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/fec75a9048404de0b32ca91500a14f19_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_43_detail.jpg"]
"""

for url in re.findall("(https?://[^\"]+)", s):
    print(url)
```

Output:

```
https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/c6f0aede76f849a18a27a91500a0c8c9_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_01_standard.jpg
https://assets.adidas.com/videos/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/dd37d9bb5cd54406b36faa8d00fb8c22_d98c/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_video.jpg
https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/690c7ca0531a450187cda91500a0dffa_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_02_standard.jpg
https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/fde9d7c8cde6427aae8ca91500a0ec61_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_03_standard.jpg
https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/01d85160ccd442a59954a91500a120cf_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_04_standard.jpg
https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/73c3160607ab42a3816ca91500a12de3_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_05_standard.jpg
https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/46bcee5e26084cffb1aba91500a0d487_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_06_standard.jpg
https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/5ecde2b36fb4425ca67aa97b012ee1e4_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_07_standard.jpg
https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/50f65fa2a60946a8990ba91500a13a53_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_41_detail.jpg
https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/3c7047a003154900905fa91500a1449f_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_42_detail.jpg
https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/fec75a9048404de0b32ca91500a14f19_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_43_detail.jpg
```

A more practical way might be to use [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
import json

s = """
"image":["https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/c6f0aede76f849a18a27a91500a0c8c9_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_01_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/videos/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/dd37d9bb5cd54406b36faa8d00fb8c22_d98c/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_video.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/690c7ca0531a450187cda91500a0dffa_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_02_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/fde9d7c8cde6427aae8ca91500a0ec61_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_03_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/01d85160ccd442a59954a91500a120cf_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_04_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/73c3160607ab42a3816ca91500a12de3_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_05_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/46bcee5e26084cffb1aba91500a0d487_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_06_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/5ecde2b36fb4425ca67aa97b012ee1e4_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_07_standard.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/50f65fa2a60946a8990ba91500a13a53_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_41_detail.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/3c7047a003154900905fa91500a1449f_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_42_detail.jpg","https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/fec75a9048404de0b32ca91500a14f19_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_43_detail.jpg"]
"""

for url in json.loads(f"{{{s}}}")["image"]:
    print(url)
```

Which also yields the same outputs.

---

With the web scraping:

```
import requests
import re

endpoint = "https://www.adidas.com.au/continental-80-shoes/G27707.html"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36'
}
response = requests.get(endpoint, headers = headers)
data = response.text

for url in re.findall("(https?://[^\"]+)", data):
    if url.endswith(".jpg"):
        print(url)
```

Output:

```
https://assets.adidas.com/images/h_840,f_auto,q_auto:sensitive,fl_lossy/c6f0aede76f849a18a27a91500a0c8c9_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_01_standard.jpg
https://assets.adidas.com/images/h_840,f_auto,q_auto:sensitive,fl_lossy/c6f0aede76f849a18a27a91500a0c8c9_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_01_standard.jpg
https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/c6f0aede76f849a18a27a91500a0c8c9_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_01_standard.jpg
https://assets.adidas.com/videos/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/dd37d9bb5cd54406b36faa8d00fb8c22_d98c/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_video.jpg
https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/690c7ca0531a450187cda91500a0dffa_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_02_standard.jpg
https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/fde9d7c8cde6427aae8ca91500a0ec61_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_03_standard.jpg
https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/01d85160ccd442a59954a91500a120cf_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_04_standard.jpg
https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/73c3160607ab42a3816ca91500a12de3_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_05_standard.jpg
https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/46bcee5e26084cffb1aba91500a0d487_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_06_standard.jpg
https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/5ecde2b36fb4425ca67aa97b012ee1e4_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_07_standard.jpg
https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/50f65fa2a60946a8990ba91500a13a53_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_41_detail.jpg
https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/3c7047a003154900905fa91500a1449f_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_42_detail.jpg
https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/fec75a9048404de0b32ca91500a14f19_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_43_detail.jpg
https://www.adidas.com.au/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-adidas-AU-Library/default/dw3836ffca/UB21.jpg
https://www.adidas.com.au/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-adidas-AU-Library/default/dw3836ffca/UB21.jpg
https://www.adidas.com.au/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-adidas-AU-Library/default/dw2168293e/001Predator.jpg
https://www.adidas.com.au/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-adidas-AU-Library/default/dwba05b161/UB19_FLY_NAV.jpg
https://www.adidas.com.au/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-adidas-AU-Library/default/dwe71a6606/basketball-nav-image-harden-vol-4.jpg
https://www.adidas.com.au/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-adidas-AU-Library/default/dwd01baad1/header-redesign/Header_images_training.jpg
https://www.adidas.com.au/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-adidas-AU-Library/default/dw65d0286b/originals-header-nav-09072018.jpg
https://www.adidas.com.au/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-adidas-AU-Library/default/dw8f5aa9d6/adidas-logo-menu-2.jpg
https://www.adidas.com.au/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-adidas-AU-Library/default/dwb2983276/fos_ath_172x80%20%281%29.jpg
https://www.adidas.com.au/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-adidas-AU-Library/default/dw0157489a/172x80_ASMC_FW20.jpg
https://www.adidas.com.au/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-adidas-AU-Library/default/dw28fcced9/skateheaderline.jpg
https://www.adidas.com.au/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-adidas-AU-Library/default/dw921d9920/skateboarding.jpg
https://www.adidas.com.au/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-adidas-AU-Library/default/dw81dcc2a2/Adidas_2020_Sustainability_nav_headline.jpg
https://www.adidas.com.au/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-adidas-AU-Library/default/dwded2c44e/Adidas_2020_Sustainability_nav_image.jpg
https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_600,f_auto,q_auto/c6f0aede76f849a18a27a91500a0c8c9_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_01_standard.jpg
https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_320,f_auto,q_auto:sensitive,fl_lossy/8df5ab4346d7475ebb08a91500a047d3_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_White_G27706_01_standard.jpg
https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_320,f_auto,q_auto:sensitive,fl_lossy/c6f0aede76f849a18a27a91500a0c8c9_9366/Continental_80_Shoes_Black_G27707_01_standard.jpg
```

Comment: @asadkhan Is there anything wrong with my solution? Thanks!

Comment: wonder if this is some type of assignment. I answered a similar question as well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66352130/unable-print-the-name-and-price/66356013#66356013)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
import re

s = '''your string'''

URL_RE = re.compile('https://[^"]+')
urls = URL_RE.findall(s)
print(urls)
```

The regex `https://[^"]+` means match **https://** following by one or more **non-double quote** characters.